# Rails 2.3 - What is the most efficient way to persist large amounts of search data to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Users on my web app generate about 100k search requests per day (product catalogue), each request consists of a search term, category id, users ip and a timestamp. I have a single instance of MySQL - no replication or master / slave setup.

I am worried that all these writes will impact the performance of the app, just wondering how others have handled this situation with similar infrastructure?

I've thought about writing the logs to a simple csv file during the day and then a night, when there is very little web traffic, setup a rake task to import these records into the applicable table....this just does not "smell right" though.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is several common pattern to scaling from the beginning.

First off, split your system to 2 layers: APP, DB. Each of them on independent server (cloud, vps, dedic). The second step is horizontal scaling of the DB (access to data from the APP): write to master, read from slave.

Actually, you just need to start work on it, then you have more questions what is better, what is worth to try.

Some useful resources for you:

- http://railslab.newrelic.com/2009/07/16/episode-17-scaling-your-database-part-1
- http://www.slideshare.net/Blaine/scaling-twitter

Comment: take care about Caching layer, it's the more important in your case

Comment: One GitHubber guy provides a book [Scaling experts](http://scalingexperts.com/books/)

Answer (score 0):

Some more information might have helped such as: what is the configuration of the server? Are you experiencing the problems right now or just worrying that it might happen any time soon? Even if you face some problems, your current application should support you for some more time, since you are still on single server. And MySQL has many good replication features which you can use.

Also if you are storing searches for analysis purpose you can periodically move them to another database server, which is dedicated to data-mining purpose.

If are really adventurous and like to implement latest and greatest technologies, NoSQL databases is something you might want to investigate.

For high volume, big data many people seem to be favoring NoSQL databases these days. The [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/) blog has information about architecture of many high volume really popular websites.